# AdMob mediation with Millenia Media

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to setup Millenia Media as a mediation network on my AdMob account. I have added it to my AdMob account and I have set it's eCPM to be higher than AdMob (to test and see if it shows).

I have added the following to my ApplicationManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

...

<activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" ></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also, I have included MMSDK.jar and MMAdMobAdapter_1_6_0.jar in my libs folder

build.gradle

```
compile files('libs/MMSDK.jar')
compile files('libs/MMAdMobAdapter_1_6_0.jar')
```

Can anyone help me out with this one? What am I doing wrong here? AdMob ads show normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that Millennial doesn't have ads to show for you (some ad networks take a while to find inventory for a new app) and it is falling back to Admob.

Ask the Millennial guys how to get Millennial test ads when mediating with Admob.